# ember: serialize object into url for ajax

Tags: ember.js, fastboot

I'm trying FastBoot in which I don't have access to jquery.  Previously I was using jquery's param function:

```
Ember.$.param(urlData);
```

to serialize an object into a url for an AJAX request (I'm not using ember-data).  I am pretty sure ember has something built-in to do this, but I can't find it!  ember mega newb here.  Thanks!

Comment: which Ember version are you using ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: I'm using ember 2.11 with fastboot.  Fastboot doesn't have access to jquery.  I tried JSON stringify - no dice.  Ended up just going with a short function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this as a substitute. https://github.com/knowledgecode/jquery-param

You can load it via Bower and `app.import` or via npm and `ember-browserify`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is probably safer, but this also seems to work:

```
serializeToUrl(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        return key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]);
    }).join('&');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle nested params.